# setState doesn't change decoration of TextField

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dart, flutter-layout

I want to change the decoration of TextField when the onSubmitted method called, in setState when I called my function for returning InputDecoration, it doesn't change the decoration of TextField.

Actually I want to check whether user filling the TextField correctly or not, if not warned them by changing the decoration of TextField.

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final IconData icon;
  final String textLabel;
  final TextInputType textInputType;
  CustomTextField(
      this.controller, this.icon, this.textLabel, this.textInputType);
  @override
  _CustomTextFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();

}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  InputDecoration inputDecoration;
  double a = 0;
  bool b = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    inputDecoration = noramlInputDecoration(context, widget.textLabel, Icon(widget.icon));
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: responsiveHeight(context, 0.8)),
      child: TextField(
        onSubmitted: (mahdi) {
          print('adfaf');
          setState(() {
            inputDecoration = noramlInputDecoration(
                context, widget.textLabel, Icon(widget.icon));
          });
          a++;
          print(a);
        },
        decoration: inputDecoration,
        onTap: () {},
        toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
          paste: true,
          copy: true,
          cut: true,
          selectAll: true,
        ),
        cursorWidth: 2,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: responsiveWidthGivenWidth(
                responsiveWidth(context, 81.6) / 10, 53.3),
            height: 0.5),
        controller: widget.controller,
        maxLines: 1,
        obscureText: b,
        showCursor: true,
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        keyboardType: widget.textInputType,
        inputFormatters: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here are my two method for returning InputDecoration.

```
InputDecoration errorInputDecoration(
    BuildContext context, IconData icon, String hintText, String errorText) {
  InputDecoration inputDecoration;
  inputDecoration = InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        right: responsiveWidthGivenWidth(responsiveWidth(context, 81.6), 5.2),
      ),
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: blue,
      ),
    ),
    hintText: hintText,
    errorText: errorText,
    errorMaxLines: 2,
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 2,
      ),
    ),
    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 4,
      ),
    ),
  );
  return inputDecoration;
}

InputDecoration noramlInputDecoration(
    BuildContext context, String hintText, Icon icon) {
  return InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        right: responsiveWidthGivenWidth(responsiveWidth(context, 81.6), 5.2),
      ),
      child: Icon(
        icon.icon,
        color: blue,
      ),
    ),
    hintText: hintText,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.blue[200],
        width: 2,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: `setState()` calls the build method. so the value that you are assigning to `inputDecoration` inside `setState` is being overriden by the the value you are assigning to it in the first line of  `build`. So try moving your initial `inputDecoration` assignment from `build` to somewhere outside `build`, preferable inside `initState`.

Comment: Oh I understand now, I do what you said and it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ryosuke said in the comment of the question, I shouldn't use setState() in the build method because every time it called and it stuck in loop and always called build() method.